# Get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject()Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive;

Tags: java, digital-signature

I have trying sign pdf with digital signature using java. I have get an exception . The exception is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject()Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive;
>        at MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

Please help me.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace and the relevant code please

Comment: You've got a mismatch between the versions of JARs.

Comment: Thanks Marko Topolnik. can you tell me the compatible  java version for itextpdf-5.3.5.jar,bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47.jar,bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.47.jar

Comment: the complete code is here:

Comment: Hello Jens ! I can not sent the full code in the comment. How will I sent you the code?